# Is there anything like a "blank" blockchain?

Tags: altcoin

I'm looking to create a coin with my own method of securing the network. Is there anything close to something I could create my own algorithm and replace that portion of the code with my own? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. Do all of the normal steps for creating an altcoin. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=225690.0

Then, replace the `CheckProofOfWork` function with something else.

Comment: Methinks we need this answer as a template :)